# Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

When I execute code below error should be there :

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error
>   communicating with the remote browser. It may have died. Build info:
>   version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 16:57:40'

My code is following :

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.browserlaunchers.locators.*;


public class Login {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        String baseUrl = " http://10.37.55.109/Exide_Esam/admin.html";
        driver.get(baseUrl);
        driver.findElement(By.id("txtUser")).sendKeys("ZASADMIN");
        driver.findElement(By.id("txtPass")).sendKeys("Test");
        WebElement checkbox;
        checkbox = driver.findElement(By.className("checkbox-material"));
        if(!checkbox.isSelected())
        {
            checkbox.click();
        }
        driver.findElement(By.id("btnLogin")).click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()=' Master']")).click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class = 'mobile-view `enter code here`visible-xs']//ul[@class = 'sub-menu-list']//li[@id = 'SubMenu-1']")).click();

        driver.quit();
```

Comment: Is that happening immediately during the initialization or when the browser is actually running?

Comment: check compatibility between browser version and selenium version..AFAIK selenium 2.53.0 can go well with FF 46.0.1 version for 47 version you need to add MarionetteDriver as capability to firefoxdriver's capabilities.